# How set Boolean true in smali

Tags: boolean, smali

I have this in .smali file

```
invoke-virtual {p1, v0}, Landroid/widget/RadioButton;->setEnabled(Z)V
```

and i need to set true in SetEnabled.
If i replace Z to 1 or true then apktool throwing a error

> no viable alternative at input '1'

How to set bool true correctly?

Answer (score 2):

```
const/4 v0, 0x1

invoke-virtual {p1, v0}, Landroid/widget/RadioButton;->setEnabled(Z)V
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.